# Pylint. How to disable graph?

Tags: python, code-analysis, pylint

I'm using [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) for code analysis. When I run `pylint` I see long output about dependencies. It looks like this:

```
External dependencies
---------------------
::

    example_lib (my_project.pack1.name_module)
    pack1 (pack1.pack2.name_module1,pack1.pack2.name_module2,...)
      \-...
    ... # long list of dependencies here
```

How can I disable this graph? Does anyone know some parameter for `pylint config` to disable `External dependencies` output?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to disable report RP0401. You can do this on the command line with `pylint -d RP0401`, or in .pylintrc append 'RP0401' to the list on the line beginning `disable=` (in section `[MESSAGES CONTROL]`).